# Retrieve user information from ASPNetUsers table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am really new to using Blazor WASM and the ASP.NET Core hosted. I have set up the login which stores all registered users to the ASPNetUsers table. I am wondering how I can then retrieve these users to display information to other users. For example I am looking to be able to have a user logged in who can then search all other users who have registered into the application as well. How might I go about displaying a list of all the users who have registered onto the application, stored in ASPNetUsers table

### Options

[image]

### Retrieve and send back

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> Get()
    {
        var result = userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault();

        User x = new User();
        x.Username = result.Email;

        List<User> giveback = new List<User>();
        giveback.Add(x);
        
        return giveback;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve all users access the Users property on the UserManager:

```
var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();
```

The image in your post shows that you are only accessing the static members.  You are not using an instance of UserManager.

You need to inject an instance into your controller:

```
readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public MyController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Ticket>> Get()
{
   var user = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try and do the above code, I do not get "Users" appearing with my UserManager object.

Comment: Is the UserManager you're accessing from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.users?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_Users

Comment: Yeah. I have edited to post to show the properties I get

Comment: Answer updated,

Comment: Thanks for getting back. The ApplicationUser is on the server side inside a Models folder. When I try doing @using ProjectName.Server.Models it seems to not recognise it. How would I access the ApplicationUser class from my razor page to make http requests?

Comment: You're trying to access this directly from client-size razor components?  That won't work, nor should it.  Your WASM client and Server have references to the Shared project.  You'll need to provide an API that returns a collection of User DTOs defined in your Shared project for the client to consume.  All of my advice above relates to how you can get at the users server-side.  The provision of data to the WASM client is done via shared classes (DTOs) from the shared project.

Comment: Would you recommend making a class "UserDTO" which inherits IdentityUser. Then use this UserTDO for client interaction

Comment: Yes, use a DTO.  No, don't inherit.  Just map the required details from IdentityUser to UserDTO before returning to the client.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I have edited the post above to show how I am doing it and the way I understood it. Sorry for the back and fourth

Comment: Yup.  Personally, I like to actually name my DTO with the suffix, e.g. "UserDTO".  That way there's no confusion between the UserDTO and "User" in any other object model.

Comment: Ah okay. In the case of wanting to return all users and not just one via  FirstOrDefault how might I loop through the users in userManager.Users and assign them to a User object respectively  and then send a list of these users back. Would I use a lambda expression of some kind. Really appreciate you taking the time to help me out

Comment: List<UserDto> userDtos = UserManager.Users.Select(u => new UserDto() { Name = u.Name, Etc = u.Etc}).ToList();

Comment: Read up on Linq for this type of manipulation of IEnumerables such as List.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help, appreciate it!